# Execute Shortcode in Textfile

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I´ve tried everything I know (include file, file_get_contents, "IncludeMe"-Plugin and others) to execute a shortcode within a textfile, but it didn´t work.

So here is the problem detailed and I hope somebody could help me: I´m taking different rows of post_content from a textfile this way:

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$pm_row = get_post_meta($postid, 'pm_row', true);
```

It works so far, but in some of those rows are different shortcodes embedded. They don´t work and were always shown as plain text instead, although they are all functionel - outside of this textfile.

What am I missing?

Any hints for this?

Comment: ...and ...of course.... I´m echoing the content/row afterwards...

Comment: ´´´ global $wp_query;
echo $texto[$pm_row]; ´´´

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: $text = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'wptext/more_text.txt';
$texto = file($text);

Comment: @benJ: Thanks, but didn´t get it. What is the use of this link to the shortcode reference? Like I wrote...those shortcodes are already working - outside of those textfiles....

Comment: Yes, and therefor you still have to do something, so that they work “inside those text files” (very weird phrasing, in combination with the code you have shown) - and that is, use that function, to parse and “execute” these short codes in that contet you just read from the database here.

Comment: Exactly...that´s what I´m asking for: How to "...use that function, to parse and “execute” these short codes..." in a textfile?

Comment: ...ok, here again a summary of what I´m presenting before - perhaps in a bit confusing way.

So, this....
`
$text = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'wptext/more_text.txt'; 
$texto = file($text); 

global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$pm_row = get_post_meta($postid, 'pm_row', true);

global $wp_query; 
echo $texto[$pm_row];
`

...is working fine, except that embedded shortcodes are only shown as plain text but are not executed.

What´s the problem here?